# Monitoring CPU usage in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, central-processing-unit, resources

How to find out what process is using CPU to what extent in Ubuntu? I'd like to have real-time data as well as recorded history. Both console and GUI apps would be great.

The situation is that my system seems to be really overloaded right now and I don't know why for sure. I've spent some time killing processes and watching if performance improves. And I suspect that JS Scripts running in Mozilla are causing problems. All in all a nice tool for taking a look at CPU usage would come in handy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tried [Htop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/) ?

Comment: Yep, great tool, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

Learn to use "sar", you'll be glad you did.

Install the "sysstat" package. It will record tons of useful system statistics, CPU, memory usage, I/O, and more. The default retention period is 7 days I believe.

Then you can go back in time for the day you want like this (for the 2nd, for example):

sar -C -f /var/log/sysstat/sa02

Answer (score 2):

top will give you real time data. Recorded may be more tricky.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools you may use :
dstat, vmstat, htop, ps ..

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a desktop you can also use the system monitor in gnome or kde.  Both will list the processes similar to the Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SeaLion](https://sealion.com). The default command lists has  `top -b -n1` which will do exactly what you are looking for. It has real-time data as well as recorded history.